# Why are my fonts not loading up correctly?

Tags: sass, google-font-api, google-fonts

I'm practicing with SCSS and two minutes ago my code was working, before splitting the variables and creating the folder structure.

But now, no matter what I change, there's no way to change the font. It just loads with Times New Roman.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">

    <title>Tours</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__logo-box">
            <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="Logo" class="header__logo">
        </div>

        <div class="header__text-box">
            <h1 class="heading-primary">
                <span class="heading-primary--main">Outdoors</span>
                <span class="heading-primary--sub">is where life happens.</span>
            </h1>

            <a href="#section-tours" class="btn btn--white btn--animated">Discover our tours</a>
        </div>
    </header>


</body>

    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        /*font-size: 16px;*/
        line-height: 1.7;
        color: $color-grey-dark;
        padding: 3rem;
    }

    .heading-primary {
        color: $color-white;
        text-transform: uppercase;

        backface-visibility: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 6rem;
        }

The imports are ok, so it should be working.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine in jsfiddle. It's displaying Lato as the font. Did you try clearing your cache? You could also try changing the link to:

```php
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will give an unlimited swap period to load the font if it takes to long to download before render.